# How to replace the items from given dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am a newbie in python. I was playing with dictionaries and wanted to know the solution to the given problem

```
list_ = [['any', 'window', 'says', 'window'], ['dog', 'great'], ['after', 'end', 'explains', 'income', '.', '?']] 

dictionary=[('dog', 'cat'), ('window', 'any')]

def replace_matched_items(word_list, dictionary):
    int_word = []
    int_wordf = []
    for lst in word_list:
        for ind, item in enumerate(lst):
            for key,value in dictionary:
                if item in key:
                    lst[ind] = key 
                else:
                    lst[ind] = "NA"
        int_word.append(lst)
    int_wordf.append(int_word)
    return int_wordf
list_ = replace_matched_items(list_, dictionary)
print(list_ )
```

Output generated is:

```
[[['NA', 'window', 'NA', 'window'], ['NA', 'NA'], ['NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA']]]
```

The expected output is:

```
 [[['NA', 'window', 'NA', 'window'], ['dog', 'NA'], ['NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA']]]
```

I am using python 3
Thanks in advance

Comment: The variable named `dictionary` is not a dictionary: it is a list of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Some quick introduction to data structures in python just to clarify your question.

- A **list** is similar to your arrays, where they can be accessed via their index and are **mutable** meaning items within the list can be changed. Lists are generally identified by *brackets* []. 
  For example:

```
my_array = [4, 8, 16, 32]
print(my_array[0]) # returns 4
print(my_array[3]) # returns 32

my_array[2] = 0
print(my_array) # returns [4, 8, 0, 32]
```

- A **tuple** is similar to a list, however, the main difference is that they are **immutable** meaning items within the tuple cannot be changed. Items can still be accessed via their index. They are generally identified by *parenthesis* (). 
  For example:

```
my_tuple = ('this', 'is', 'a', 'tuple', 'of', 'strings')
print(my_tuple[0]) # returns 'this'
my_tuple[1] = 'word' # throws a 'TypeError' as items within tuples cannot be changed.
```

- A **dictionary** uses a **key and value** pair to access, store, and change data in a dictionary. Similar to lists, they are **mutable**, however, each value has their own **unique** key. To access a value in the dictionary, you have to pass the key within the dictionary. Dictionaries are generally identified by *curly braces* {}. 
  For Example:

```
my_dictionary = {'John':13, 'Bob':31, 'Kelly':24, 'Ryan':17}
print(my_dictionary['Kelly']) # Returns 24

my_dictionary['Kelly'] = 56 # Assigns 56 to Kelly
print(my_dictionary['Kelly']) # Returns 56
```

The **key:value** takes this form within the dictionary, and each subsequent key-value pairs are separated by commas.

I would highly suggested reading the official documentation on the Data Structures available for python: [Link Here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

---

### To answer the question

From your code given, you've used a **tuple** with your key-value pair encapsulated the tuple in a **list** as your dictionary data structure.

Your expected output is a result of you iterating through the **entire dictionary**, and did not handle what will occur once you've found the key for your dictionary. This can be fixed by adding a **break** statement within your if-statement once a key has been found.
The **break** statement, will exit your for loop once a key has been found and, will continue onto the next list item.

Your function will end up looking like:

```
def replace_matched_items(word_list, dictionary):
    int_word = []
    int_wordf = []
    for lst in word_list:
        for ind, item in enumerate(lst):
            for key,value in dictionary:
                if item in key:
                    lst[ind] = key
                    break
                else:
                    lst[ind] = "NA"
        int_word.append(lst)
    int_wordf.append(int_word)
    return int_wordf
```

### Suggested to use a Dictionary

Using a Dictionary data structure for your key and value pairs will let you have access to methods that'll let you check whether a key exists inside your dictionary.

If you have a list of keys, and you'd like to check if a dictionary key exists within a list:

```
this_list = ['any', 'window', 'says', 'window', 'dog', 
'great', 'after', 'end', 'explains', 'income', '.', '?']

dictionary = {'dog':'cat', 'window':'any'}

matched_list = []
for keys in dictionary:
    if keys in this_list:
        matched_list.append(keys) # adds keys that are matched 
    else:
        # do something if the key is in not the dictionary

print(matched_list)
# Returns ['dog', 'window']
```

Comment: Thanks JeReq The problem is with dictionary as in python 3 it returns list of tuples in a list.